# Normal vector of a riemannian submanifold in normal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $\Sigma \subset B_r(x) \subset M$ be an embedded hypersurface of dimension $n-1$, with empty boundary and with a normalvector field $\nu$. Here $B_r(x) $ is a geodesic neighborhood of $x \in M$.

If now in addition $x \in \Sigma$ we can construct an orthonormal basis of $T_x M$ with $e_1 = \nu,e_2,...,e_n$. Let now be $\phi_x:B_r(x) \to \mathbb{R}$ be normal coordinate system in $x$ with respect to this basis. Then we get a hypersurface $\phi(\Sigma) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Is then the vector $e_1=(1,0,...0)$ the normal vector of the surface $\phi(\Sigma) $ in the point $0=\phi(x)  \in\phi(\Sigma) $ ?

Comment: Why does $x$ belong to $\Sigma$? Also, you have a typo in the definition of $\phi_x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean? $\Sigma$ is a submanifold of $M$ and I interpret it as a subset that lies in some geodesic neighborhood of $x$ in $M$ and I choose normal coordinates with rspect to the manifold $M$. Did I use the wrong terminology?

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed the "if now in addition $x\in\Sigma$." The derivative of the exponential map $\exp_x$ (which is the inverse of $\phi_x$) is the identity at $x$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry but I don't understand if that means that the new hypersurface $\phi_x(\Sigma)$ has (1,0,...0) as its normal vector. I see that this means means that the $\phi^{-1}_*(1,0,...0) = \nu$ but I don't understand why it is the normal of $\phi_x(\Sigma)$

Comment: Isn't the identity map angle-preserving? What vectors span $T_x\Sigma$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahh, I see. Thank you, I didn't think of it that way. Because it stands orthogonal on the other vectors.